# Use convert statement in SQL : Error

Tags: mysql, sql

I am receiving an error as I try to convert my datetime column called rent_date to `mm/dd/yyyy` format.

I have consulted the relevant  [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql#BKMK_examples) but still receive error.

SQL statement:

```
SELECT listing.title , listing.author, listing.isbn, listing.cond , listing.additional_information, CAST(rented_listings.due_date as date), CONVERT(date, rented_listings.rent_date, 101) 
        FROM `listing` 
        INNER JOIN  `rented_listings` ON `listing`.`upload_id` = `rented_listings`.`upload_id` 
        WHERE  `availability`= 'R' ORDER BY `rented_listings`.`due_date` ASC , `rented_listings`.`rent_date` DESC
```

Error is within this part of the query
    CONVERT(date, rented_listings.rent_date, 101) which makes sense because when I take it out the query works.

How do I convert 'rented_listing.rent_date' to mm/dd/yyyy?

EDIT: 
Specific error included:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
>         'rented_listings.rent_date, 101) 
>           FROM `listing` 
>           INNER JOIN`' at line 1

Comment: Please pick only MySQL or sqlserver tags; your database cannot be both! Your other tags are probably also irrelevant. Always include the actual error message on your SO question if you're getting an error. "I'm getting some error but I'm not going to tell you what it is" is perhaps the single most frustrating thing you can say to tech support

Comment: @CaiusJard Thank you for the feedback. The reason I didn't think the specific error would be helpful to include in this case is because it is pretty generic and only indicates the portion of the query that is erroneous, which i had already made clear.

Comment: @CaiusJard How do I know if my database is MySQL or sqlserver, just curious? I'm using phpmyadmin through MAMP.

Comment: @BiniyamAsnake seriously, you don't know which database your are working with?

Comment: Err.. if you don't know what database you're using I think you have slightly bigger problems. Go find out what database you're using and come back; we ant do this step for you and it's kinda fundamental to your programming career that you know what tools you're using

Comment: The error message and the query syntax all points to MySql, but you are linking to the documentation of SQL Server. Those are two different products. Try reading the documentation of **MySql** instead.

Comment: better convert the date to varchar

Comment: @BiniyamAsnake **THIS** is what you should be reading https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert

Comment: Check MySQL version: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%"`; check sqlserver version: `SELECT @@VERSION`  . These queries will each fail if used on the wrong database

Comment: Thank you for the help everyone. I realized I was reading the incorrect documentation and have found the right sql query. To convert to the format I originally I asked use: date_format(NOW(), '%m-%d-%Y')

Comment: thats what I recommened :)

Comment: The very specific error message you posted says "check your MySQL manual.." - how can you have been in any doubt as to what database you were using?! Lessons to take away from this: always READ the exact error you're getting and always post the exact error you're getting

Comment: Lesson learned. @CaiusJard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should do like this in mysql

```
DATE_FORMAT(cast(rented_listings.rent_date as date), '%m/%d/%Y');
```

which will first convert it to the date and then to the specific format

Comment: No need to do that cast?

Comment: did just to be on the safe side :)